# Getting the following error - Error:(6, 39) error: package com.crashlytics.android.answers does not exist

Tags: android, google-fabric

Following the install instructions via fabric and doing everything via Android Studio but I'm getting the following errors

> Error:(6, 39) error: package com.crashlytics.android.answers does not exist
>   Error:(26, 29) error: package io.fabric.sdk.android does not exist
>   Error:(66, 27) error: cannot find symbol class Answers
>   Error:(66, 5) error: cannot find symbol variable Fabric

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by following the manual installation on the Fabric website.